# How can I use keypress events as variables throughout my code? (Python, Mac)

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to write a code that takes in user input at any time (in the form of keypresses) and depending on the conditions when the user presses certain keys, conditions would change. This is what I have so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

timeout = time.time() + 30

def keypress(event):
    global alive
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        alive = False

    x = event.char

    if x == "l":
        print("hello")
    elif x == "s":
        print("no")
    elif x == "r":
        print("maybe")
    elif x == "g":
        print("bye")
    else:
        print(x)


root = tk.Tk()

print("Press a key (Escape key to exit):")

root.bind_all('<Key>', keypress)

global alive
alive = True


while alive:

    start = time.time()
    if time.time() > timeout:
        print "Game Over" 
        break

 # do stuff here, this is in my main loop where I am trying to put the 'if' statements

    root.update()
```

This code takes in certain keypresses, and prints out the respective lines depending on the keypress. The while loop allows this to happen for a certain amount of time before "Game Over". What I'm trying to do is set if statements within my while loop using the keypresses as input. For example (something along the lines of):

```
if x == 'l' and sound == True:
    print "bla blabla"
    sound == False
elif x == 'l' and sound == False:
    print "blahblahblah"
    sound == True
```

The problem is I keep getting an error message that says 'x is not defined', or something along those lines. Please help!
Also, I'm using a Mac.

Comment: need the code indented so we can see the blocks...

Comment: it looks like a block to me, should I indent each line by 4 more spaces?

Comment: Everything is left aligned when I'm looking it, course it is IE 7 on this box...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - indentation looks fine on XP/FF22...

Comment: Why am I not surprised. :(

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` is defined within your `keypress()` function, and is not available outside that function. Therefore, your `if x == 1` statement is raising an error.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I make it so that I can use 'x' as a variable outside my keypress() function?

Comment: you've used `global` elsewhere in your code, does that work for `x`?

Comment: I've tried putting `global x` right under `global alive`. And then another `global x` right under `while alive:` and it gives me the error that "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined"

Comment: please [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17603419/edit) your question with your current code, and the full stack trace (including line numbers) - it'll help us figure out where exactly the problem is. Also, what version of Python are you using?